# django registration form does not save information

Tags: django

I am new to django . here I want to register user and I have a problem whenever the user hit signup button in registration.html nothing happens and when I go to the admin section no user saved so here are my codes

note : all functions and templates works as expected , I think the problem in 
UserFormView or urls.py

views.py :

```
from django.http import Http404
from  .models import Category, Item , Order
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate , login
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import UsrForm


class IndexView(generic.ListView) :
    template_name = 'res/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_categories'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Category.objects.all()


def detail(request, category_name):
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(category_title = category_name)
        all_categories = Category.objects.all()
        items = category.items.all()
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Category does not exist")

    return render(request, 'res/menu.html', {'items': items,'all_categories': all_categories})


class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UsrForm
    template_name = 'res/registration.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request , self.template_name, {'form' : form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            user = authenticate(username=username , password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request , user)
                    return redirect('res')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view() , name='menu'),

    url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view() , name='register'),

    url(r'^(?P<category_name>[a-z]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

forms.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UsrForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username' , 'email' , 'password' ]
```

here is registration.py :

```
{% extends 'res/base.html' %}
{% block section %}
<h2>Sign up</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
          <p>
            {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
            {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
              <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
            {% endif %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
              <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
          </p>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: maybe your form is not valid, add a `else` clause for  `if form.is_valid()`  this line